# java Vector and thread safety

Tags: java, vector, multithreading, thread-safety

I'm wondering if this code will do any trouble:

I have a vector that is shared among many threads. Every time a thread has to add/remove stuff from the vector I do it under a `synchronized` block. However, the main thread has a call:

```
System.out.println("the vector's size: "+ vec.size());
```

which isn't `synchronized`.

Should this cause trouble?

Comment: As an aside you should favour using the JDK 1.2 Collections API (ArrayList or LinkedList) in conjunction with Collections.synchronizedList(List) to make them synchronized.  Vector is obsolete (along with Hashtable).

Comment: @Adamski Thanks for your comment, that helped me alot (although 3 years old)! ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you are referring to `java.util.Vector`.

Actually `Vector.size()` *is* synchronized and will return a value consistent with the vector's state (when the thread calling `size()` enters the monitor.)  If it returns 42, then at some point in time the vector contained exactly 42 elements.

If you're adding items in a loop in another thread then you cannot predict the exact size, but it should be fine for monitoring purposes.

Comment: +1 for "at some point in time". Might not be exactly consistent with the code surrounding the statement. For that you'd need to add your own synchronization.

Answer (score 12):

All Vector methods are synchronized themselves, so as long as you are only synchronizing around a single method, your own synchronization is not necessary. If you have several method calls, which depend on each other, e.g. something like `vec.get(vec.size()-2)` to get the second last element, you have to use your own synchronization since otherwise, the vector may change between vec.size() and vec.get().

Answer (score 0):

Each of the methods of `java.util.Vector` is `synchronized`, so this won't cause any problems for something that is just logging the size.

To improve performance you may be better off replacing your `Vector` with an `ArrayList`. The methods of `ArrayList` aren't `synchronized`, so you would need to synchronize all access yourself.

Comment: Which performance improvements do you expect if you replace the syncrhonized Vector class with an unsynchronized ArrayList and add your own synchronization around all method calls on the ArrayList?

Comment: In many cases, single-method synchronization is insufficient, so you have to do your own synchronization anyway. Using Vector, you'd then end up synchronizing twice.

Comment: How much performance impact do you expect from the "double" synchronization if you implement something like `synchronized(vec) {vec.get(vec.size()-2);}`?

Comment: If you manually synchronize on the vector itself, then the overhead is negligible. If you're synchronizing on another object, then there is more of an overhead (I've just done some quick tests that show ArrayList to be about 25% faster in this situation with no thread contention).

Answer (score 0):

Mind that you can always obtain a synchronized version of a collection by using `Collections.synchronizedCollection(Collection<T> c)` static method..

Comment: In this case the collection is a List, so Collections.synchronizedList(List<T> c) would be better.